# How to override logic of specific drush command?

Tags: hooks, drush

I'm aware of [`validate`](http://api.drush.org/api/drush/drush.api.php/function/drush_hook_COMMAND_validate/8.0.x)/[`pre`](http://api.drush.org/api/drush/drush.api.php/function/drush_hook_pre_COMMAND/8.0.x)/[`post`](http://api.drush.org/api/drush/drush.api.php/function/drush_hook_post_COMMAND/8.0.x) COMMAND hooks and I would like to replace the logic of the existing drush command on specific condition using *[policy commandfile](http://api.drush.ws/api/drush/examples%21policy.drush.inc/8.0.x)* with something else, e.g.

```
/**
 * Implementation of drush_hook_COMMAND_validate().
 *
 * Validate feature revert of specific module.
 */
function drush_policy_features_revert_validate() {
  if (strpos($args[1], 'rules') !== FALSE) {
    drush_invoke_process('@self', 'rules-revert-all');
    drush_print('Rules reverted in custom way!');
    return drush_set_error('POLICY_DENY', dt('Rules features already reverted.'));
  } 
}
```

However the problem is when I return `TRUE` - the command which I want to override is called after than, on the other hand when I'm returning `FALSE`, the `drush` will fail with non-zero exit code which could cause some other issues (like breaking the deployment).

Is there any better way of overriding the logic of existing drush command without described side-effects? Secondly *validation* hook doesn't sound right to implement that kind of logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually returning just FALSE without `drush_set_error` should work fine without error and the original command isn't executed, e.g.

```
/**
 * Validate feature revert of specific module.
 *
 * Implementation of drush_hook_COMMAND_validate().
 *
 */
function drush_policy_features_revert_validate() {
  $args = drush_get_arguments();
  if (strpos($args[1], 'rules') !== FALSE) {
    drush_log(dt('Reverting rules...'), 'ok');
    drush_invoke_process('@self', 'rules-revert-all');
    drush_log(dt('Reverting of rules finished.'), 'ok');
    // drush_postflight(); // Set context as completed, but this is not needed.
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```